# Binding an EXCEL worksheet to a dataGridView?

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind an EXCEL datasheet to a **dataGridView**? I think that this is close but I do not know why the data is not showing up in the grid. I have seen several post on Stackoverflow but I could not get any of them to work. So I decided to put my own example up and see if I can get someone to try this code. All the form needs is a button with the click event and the dataGridView.

**Class Code:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace TestExcel
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                String name = "Items";
                String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                @"C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\test.xls" + 
                                ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";

                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
                con.Open();

                OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(data);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `dataGridView1.DataBind();` at the end?

Comment: which version of excel you are using ?

Comment: please see the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `connection string` Provider to the below given as , check in your excel file name is "test.xls" and sheet name is "Items" or not ?

```
 String filenamewithpath = @"C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\test.xls";

 String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filenamewithpath +
                          ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
```

here is the complete code.Works 100%

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "Items";
        String filenamewithpath = @"C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\test.xls";

        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filenamewithpath +
                                 ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: I just set it up in my Visual C# and made a test spread sheet. I was testing this at work earlier but then at home here I don't have Excel 2010. I saved as a Microsoft 97,2000,XP will this still work. If not I will try it Monday when I get to work. I did name the Sheet to Items because that is what, I think that is what the SELECT statement references for the data source. You would think that this would work, even with an old version of EXCEL but I am wondering if this will work if it is a file saved in Open Office in a EXEL format. Doug Hauf

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `dataGridView1.DataBind()` after `dataGridView1.DataSource = data;`

Comment: this a windows application and there is no need of dataGridView1.DataBind();